# OWLAPI recursive axioms

Tags: recursion, owl-api

I have in input N + 1 items, where N are role/OWLObjectProperty and the last one is a concept/OWLClass.
The problem is that I have to produce an OWLClassExpression like this one, considering the input (a,b,C):

```
OWLClassExpression axiom = factory.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(   factory.getOWLObjectProperty( "#a") , factory.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(factory.getOWLObjectProperty("#b", C));
```

This is easy because I only have 2 roles, but I need a **general** solution for N roles, since I cannot predict the input of the user.
The axiom will be nested, but I do not know if there is a possibile to build a structure like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - you can replace C with a method call that recursively builds your expression, or you can reduce it to a list. E.g., a list of properties that you navigate in reverse order, starting at the axiomatic lever (C) and wrapping the previously created object in a new class expression.

However, the owl api has no utility class to do this, you'll have to code it from scratch.